# node-fetch error when importing lokka-transport-http in react-native

Tags: react-native, graphql

I'm trying to use `Lokka` as a client for `graphql` in my `react-native` application. I follow the very basic instructions but I get an error when importing the module `lokka-transport-http`:

```
const Transport = require('lokka-transport-http').Transport;
```

The exact error message:

```
UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module url from /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
  /Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing to an older version in the `package.json` will fix the problem for some lucky ones.

```
"lokka": "^1.7.0",
"lokka-transport-http": "1.3.2",
```

More at https://github.com/kadirahq/lokka/issues/19